# Why does docker is giving me this error while pulling

Tags: docker, containers

As you see I'm new to docker and I'm pulling container. But when I run `docker-compose up`. It gives me

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://10.0.100.10:5000/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

So I searched online and changed my DNS server. And then I ran  `docker-compose up` again it's giving me.

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://10.0.100.10:5000/v2/": context deadline exceeded
```

I'm using windows. How do I solve this?

Comment: Use the SO search bar to look for "[docker] context deadline exceeded"

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990868/7389293