# Failed to pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeflow

I am following the tutorial here about kserve https://github.com/kserve/modelmesh-serving/blob/main/docs/quickstart.md

Is this my docker&k8s issue? I have spent hours trying to debug but to no avail.

I am getting the following error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m20s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned modelmesh-serving/modelmesh-serving-mlserver-0.x-77cc8fd548-xdgvr to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    4m18s  kubelet            Pulling image "kserve/modelmesh:v0.9.0-rc0"
  Normal   Pulled     3m18s  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "kserve/modelmesh:v0.9.0-rc0" in 59.419620166s
  Normal   Created    3m18s  kubelet            Created container mm
  Normal   Started    3m17s  kubelet            Started container mm
  Normal   Pulling    3m17s  kubelet            Pulling image "seldonio/mlserver:0.5.2"
  Warning  Failed     68s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "seldonio/mlserver:0.5.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  Failed     68s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   Pulling    68s    kubelet            Pulling image "kserve/modelmesh-runtime-adapter:v0.9.0-rc0"
```

Answer (score 1):

The image you try to pull exists and is available [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mlserver/seldonio/mlserver/0.5.2/images/sha256-8c2244e2b51102d3bd7f814dc11775f304c8be5dca42ccb6a57b545d88bed1f9?context=explore). However, from what I see it's very big (`2.74 GB`). That probably means that you experienced a timeout while pull the image.

Depending on your Kubernetes cluster and use case you can do the following:

- Try a few times and it'll pull the image at some point
- Increase the `--runtime-request-timeout` in your `kubelet`
- Execute `docker pull seldonio/mlserver:0.5.2`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Rafał Leszko, The image “**seldonio/mlserver:0.5.2**” you are trying to pull is very large which possibly throws the error: **ErrImagePull: context deadline error**. You can still pull the image with `docker pull` after which the scheduling succeedes.

When the timeout is exceeded, kubelet will cancel the request, throw out an error. The possible workaround is by setting or increasing the parameter `--runtime-request-timeout duration`  via the config file(in /var/lib/kubelet) by adjusting the timeout and then pull the image by running the command **`docker pull imagename`**.

See [kubelet-config-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely have to do with your image being too big.

One thing I would do is in your deployment file,

in the spec for the container, add a resources with a request and a limit, eg

```
 resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 256Mi
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 512Mi
```

Comment: Does resources really affect the idea behind pulling an image? I mean we specify `memory` and `cpu` here not the network stuff? Or am I wrong can these things indirectly affect it?

Comment: @frostzt , yes the amount of resources does have an effect in pulling the image. Setting resource requests ensures that the container gets allocated the necessary resources and won't be starved of CPU and memory. By specifying both requests and limits, you provide Kubernetes with the necessary information to efficiently manage the container's resource allocation and prevent any single container from dominating the available resources. This practice ensures that your applications have the resources they need to operate correctly and prevent resource contention issues in the cluster.